# holding css style in a variable and using in a function php

Tags: php, html, css, colors

I have this code:

```
function getcolor();
.....other code here
      $col=220;
return $color=hsl( $col,'100%','50%');
 .. wuth this funcitoni want to get a coloring style for another function here:

function colorSequence ($seq,$position,$color,$TFBSlength){
    $nucleotides = str_split($seq);
    foreach ($nucleotides as $index => $nucl){
        if ($index == $position-1){
          echo "<span style=\"color:$color\">";<-- this line wont work ?
        }
        if ($index == $position-1 + $TFBSlength){
          echo "</span>";
          .... rest of function.
```

input string to be colored would be e.g.
 `$seq="AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA"
$color=getcolor();`

Basically I want to use the function colorsequence's parameter $color to color a certain part of the input string a certain color(which will always change)

anyone tell me whats wrong with this part of the code ?

Comment: What is the contents of $color? Try `var_dump($color);` to better understand it. I'm also curious about the `hsl(...)` function - what does it do? I can't find it in the manual, or maybe I'm looking wrong...

Comment: $color=hsl( $col,'100%','50%');
this basically is the equivalent of saying  the colorto style in is= red.  hsl is css. it refers to hue,saturation and lightness , so e.g.hsl(0,50%,50%) is a hsl color.  i am not using hex coloring as i want to make a gradient of colors

Comment: So you're calling a CSS function from PHP? That's not going to work. What you might try is `return "hsl($col,'100%','50%');";` - turning it into a string, and then sending (echo) it to the client (the browser) to evaluate - which will produce the correct color, if supported. Otherwise you'll have to implement the hsl function yourself, which shouldn't be too hard (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Converting_to_RGB)

Comment: yea i noticed this just a minute ago. thanks, sorry for this simple mistake:/